# Zedgraph Serial plotting, cant pause the time variable. Environment.tickcount improper use

Tags: c#, zedgraph

So here's my problem,            [First image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNLZm.jpg)

the highlighted portion was the time when i put the serial port close(i call it pause). Here's my code on that button:

```
 private void disconnectbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (serialPort.IsOpen == false) return;
        serialPort.Close();
    }
```

Now, my problem here is, when I reconnect my Program to Arduino, here's my code:

```
 public void connectbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {

        serialPort.PortName = portscombobox.Text;
        serialPort.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(baudratecombobox.Text);


            if (serialPort.IsOpen) return;
            serialPort.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid COM Port number... Please choose the correct COM Port number. \n Looking at Device manager will help :)");
            Application.Restart();
        }
```

The graph didn't follow the last points position, specifically the time it stopped. The curve pick the last y-value and draw it until the time I reconnect but there's no problem on the curve when disconnected/pause. You can look at the 2nd pic to show there's no feed while disconnected.
    [Second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJhdn.jpg)

When i reconnect, the graph will look like the first picture above..

I believe my problem here was the improper use of Environment.tickcount and I tried searching for the solution but unfortunately I cant solve this on my own based on my knowledge.

I want my graph will only move to its x axis(time) when I try to connect it to arduino and read the data, and my elapsed time should only run when Im only connected not disconnected.

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using ZedGraph;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string datafromcom;
    delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);

    // Starting time in milliseconds
    int tickStart = 0;
    //double time = 0;
    //int t;



    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        checkbox1.Enabled = false;
        checkbox2.Enabled = false;
        checkbox3.Enabled = false;
        checkbox4.Enabled = false;

    }



    public void connectbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {

        serialPort.PortName = portscombobox.Text;
        serialPort.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(baudratecombobox.Text);


            if (serialPort.IsOpen) return;
            serialPort.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid COM Port number... Please choose the correct COM Port number. \n Looking at Device manager will help :)");
            Application.Restart();
        }





        serialPort.DtrEnable = true;
        serialPort.RtsEnable = true;

        getbutton.Enabled = false;
        checkbox1.Enabled = true;
        checkbox2.Enabled = true;
        checkbox3.Enabled = true;
        checkbox4.Enabled = true;
        exitbutton.Enabled = false;
        connectbutton.Enabled = false;
        disconnectbutton.Enabled = true;
        portscombobox.Enabled = false;
        baudratecombobox.Enabled = false;


    }


    private void disconnectbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (serialPort.IsOpen == false) return;
        serialPort.Close();
        //tickStart += new tickStart();


        exitbutton.Enabled = true;
        connectbutton.Enabled = true;
        disconnectbutton.Enabled = false;
        portscombobox.Enabled = true;
        baudratecombobox.Enabled = true;
        checkbox1.Enabled = false;
        checkbox2.Enabled = false;
        checkbox3.Enabled = false;
        checkbox4.Enabled = false;




    }



    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //this.Size = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size;
        GraphPane myPane = z1.GraphPane;

        z1.IsShowHScrollBar = true;
        z1.IsShowVScrollBar = true;
        z1.IsEnableHZoom = true;
        z1.IsEnableVZoom = true;



        // Disable the AutoScrollRange option (because we have set the scroll range manually)
        z1.IsAutoScrollRange = true;

              // Synchronize the Axes

        z1.IsSynchronizeYAxes = true;
        z1.IsSynchronizeXAxes = true;
        z1.GraphPane.IsBoundedRanges = true;
        // Horizontal pan allowed
        z1.IsEnableHPan = true;
        z1.IsEnableVPan = true;         
        z1.IsShowPointValues = true;
        //z1.PointValueFormat = "0.00";
        z1.PointDateFormat = "d";
        // Change the color of the title
        myPane.Title.FontSpec.FontColor = Color.Black;

        myPane.Title.Text = "  ";
        myPane.XAxis.Title.Text = "Time (Seconds)";
        myPane.YAxis.Title.Text = "Sample Potential, Volts";         


        // Save 20000 points.  At 50 ms sample rate, this is one minute
        // The RollingPointPairList is an efficient storage class that always
        // keeps a rolling set of point data without needing to shift any data values
        RollingPointPairList list = new RollingPointPairList(20000);

        // Initially, a curve is added with no data points (list is empty)
        // Color is blue, and there will be no symbols
        LineItem curve = myPane.AddCurve(null, list, Color.Black, SymbolType.None);

         //Sample at 50ms intervals
        //timer1.Interval = 100;
        //timer1.Enabled = true;
        //timer1.Start();

        // Just manually control the X axis range so it scrolls continuously
        // instead of discrete step-sized jumps
        myPane.XAxis.Scale.Min = 0;
        myPane.XAxis.Scale.Max = 10;
        myPane.XAxis.Scale.MinorStep = .5;
        myPane.XAxis.Scale.MajorStep = 1;
        myPane.YAxis.Scale.Min = -10;
        myPane.YAxis.Scale.Max = 10;
        myPane.YAxis.Scale.MinorStep = .1;
        myPane.YAxis.Scale.MajorStep = 1;

        // Add gridlines to the plot, and make them gray
        myPane.XAxis.MajorGrid.IsVisible = true;
        myPane.YAxis.MajorGrid.IsVisible = true;
        myPane.XAxis.MajorGrid.Color = Color.LightGray;
        myPane.YAxis.MajorGrid.Color = Color.LightGray;


        myPane.Fill.Color = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray;


        // Make both curves thicker
        curve.Line.Width = 2F;

        // Increase the symbol sizes, and fill them with solid white
        curve.Symbol.Size = 8.0F;
        curve.Symbol.Fill = new Fill(Color.White);


        // Add a background gradient fill to the axis frame
        myPane.Chart.Fill = new Fill(Color.White,
            Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255), -45F);







        // Scale the axes
        z1.AxisChange();
        //z1.AxisChange();
        z1.GraphPane.AxisChange();

        // Save the beginning time for reference


        tickStart = Environment.TickCount;


    }

    private void exitbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    public void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            while (serialPort.BytesToRead > 0)
            {
                datafromcom = serialPort.ReadLine();

                if (datafromcom.Trim() != "")
                {

                    float dtfm = float.Parse(datafromcom);

                    //richtextbox.Text = "dynamic";

                    if (z1.GraphPane.CurveList.Count <= 0)
                        return;

                    // Get the first CurveItem in the graph
                    LineItem curve = z1.GraphPane.CurveList[0] as LineItem;
                    if (curve == null)
                        return;

                    // Get the PointPairList
                    IPointListEdit list = curve.Points as IPointListEdit;
                    // If this is null, it means the reference at curve.Points does not
                    // support IPointListEdit, so we won't be able to modify it
                    if (list == null)
                        return;


                    double time = (Environment.TickCount - tickStart) / 1000.0;



                    //curve.AddPoint(time, iDAT);
                    list.Add(time, dtfm);
                    Scale xScale = z1.GraphPane.XAxis.Scale;
                    if (time > xScale.Max - xScale.MajorStep)
                    {
                        xScale.Max = time + xScale.MajorStep ;
                        xScale.Min = xScale.Max - 10.0;
                    }



                    z1.AxisChange();

                    z1.Invalidate();


                    this.BeginInvoke(new SetTextCallback(SetText), new object[] { datafromcom });

                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception )
        {

        }
    }

    private void SetText(string text)
    {
        this.richtextbox.Text = text;
        //richtextbox.AppendText(text);
        richtextbox.ScrollToCaret();
    }


    public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {




    }



    private void resetbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        Application.Restart();

    }



}
```

}

Comment: Do you need to base your X series on time? Why not just increment foreach(double y in Yaxis){X.Add(x);x++}

Comment: Yes base on time, possible moving by 1 sec at a time. Can you tell me how to use that on my code? BTW thanks for the fast reply.

Comment: I still think you should make X "Number of seconds in sample" and use an incrementing integer value (0,1,2,3,4,5,6) rather than measuring time. Then sample RollingPointPairList list = new RollingPointPairList(20000); using Skip().Take().Average(p=>p.y) (or where() or select() based on the circumstance) to get average value for each second. That way you get the sample for each second regardless of connect/disconnect. When you reconnect, the sampling continues with the next second of data regardless of how much time has elapsed while unplugged.

Comment: Finally, with ZedGraph, you use AddPoint(x,y) where x = lastX+1 and y=RollingPointPairList.Skip((x-1)*sampleRate).Take(sampleRate).Average(p=>p.yValue)

Comment: thanks sir for the fast reply, i would try and learn how to make your suggested solution, Good Night!

Comment: I can't really grasp the solution you make, can you please sir relate it to my code above? Thanks